# creating a key, value1, value2 dictionary from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a key: value1, value2 dictionary from a byte list and having issues with it.

**Here is my list**

```
[b'Expected in April 2018',
 b'Murder At Koh E Fiza',
 b'34',
 b'06 April 2018',
 b'Subedar Joginder Singh',
 b'0',
 b'06 April 2018',
 b'Blackmail',
 b'86',
 b'06 April 2018',
 b'Missing',
 b'0',
 b'13 April 2018',
 b'October',
 b'59',
 b'13 April 2018',
 b'Mercury',
 b'0',
 b'20 April 2018',
 b'Omerta',
 b'50']
```

**I have tried following code:**

```
 b = dict(zip(list[1::3],(list[2::3]+list[0::3])))
```

but I don't get third value as key value pair.

I have also tried

```
b = dict(zip(list[1::3],list[2::3]+list[0::3]))
```

same issue I am getting following output with both of these statements

```
{b'Murder At Koh E Fiza': b'34', b'Subedar Joginder Singh': b'0', 
b'Blackmail': b'86', b'Missing': b'0', b'October': b'59', b'Mercury': b'0', 
b'Omerta': b'50'}
```

I am looking for the following output

```
b'Murder At Koh E Fiza': b'34',b'Expected in April 2018',
b'Subedar Joginder Singh': b'0',b'06 April 2018',
```

Please let me know

Comment: Can you show us what the expected result is as a dict? What you posted there is 50% dict and 50% list and 0% valid syntax.

Comment: I have provided the output of the dictionary I am looking for

Comment: I don't know what that output is supposed to be. If I paste that into a python script, I get a syntax error. It's not a dict, it's not a list, it's no valid python data structure. It's just a syntax error.

Comment: This is the current output
{b'Murder At Koh E Fiza': b'34', b'Subedar Joginder Singh': b'0', 
b'Blackmail': b'86', b'Missing': b'0', b'October': b'59', b'Mercury': b'0', 
b'Omerta': b'50'}
I need date appended with each key, value....

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking to associate a list or a tuple with each key in your dictionary. So something like this should work:

```
dict( zip(list[1::3], zip( list[2::3], list[0::3] ) ))
```

Which results in

```
{'Mercury': ('0', '13 April 2018'), 'Murder At Koh E Fiza': ('34', 'Expected in April 2018'), 'October': ('59', '13 April 2018'), 'Missing': ('0', '06 April 2018'), 'Blackmail': ('86', '06 April 2018'), 'Omerta': ('50', '20 April 2018'), 'Subedar Joginder Singh': ('0', '06 April 2018')}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` alongside with a `dict comprehension`

```
a = [b'Expected in April 2018',
 b'Murder At Koh E Fiza',
 b'34',
 b'06 April 2018',
 b'Subedar Joginder Singh',
 b'0',
 b'06 April 2018',
 b'Blackmail',
 b'86',
 b'06 April 2018',
 b'Missing',
 b'0',
 b'13 April 2018',
 b'October',
 b'59',
 b'13 April 2018',
 b'Mercury',
 b'0',
 b'20 April 2018',
 b'Omerta',
 b'50']

final = {v: [m, k] for k, v, m in zip(a, a[1:], a[2:])}

print(final.get(b'Murder At Koh E Fiza')
print(final.get(b'Subedar Joginder Singh'))
```

output:

```
[b'34', b'Expected in April 2018']
[b'0', b'06 April 2018']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find that out without zipping as well:

```
my_list = ['Expected in April 2018', 'Murder At Koh E Fiza', '34', '06 
April 2018', 'Subedar Joginder Singh', '0', '06 April 2018', 
'Blackmail', '86', '06 April 2018', 'Missing', '0', '13 April 2018', 
'October', '59', '13 April 2018', 'Mercury', '0', '20 April 2018', 
'Omerta', '50']
n = 3
composite_list = [my_list[x:x+n] for x in range(0, len(my_list),n)]
d = {n[1]: [n[0], n[2]] for n in composite_list}
```